# How to access css/js file from S3 in AWS lambda function

Tags: python, html, css, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a sample code using AWS lambda function (python) to show a html page in browser, connection with API Gateway.

I want to use css file from S3 bucket in this lambda function as a sample code.

When I try like this, but it can't. How can I use?

[image: sample_cod]

Comment: this css/js file will be accessed from browser not by lambda function. just make that it's available for public.

Comment: I cann't understand well # BugHunter , How can I do this?

Comment: when you open the link you have pasted in `href` in the browser, do you see you css code or do you get access denied error?

Comment: No, I don't see css code and show "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make /test-bucket/test.css publicly available.

Understand that Lambda is not even accessing that file during runtime, but rather only referencing it inside a String object, so neither Lambda nor API Gateway are aware that there's a .css file at all.

When your function is executed through API Gateway, your Lambda is going to return a String containing your HTML code inside it. The browser will then try to render that HTML, meaning that the Browser itself is trying to load a file which is private inside one of your Buckets. It's exactly the same thing as creating a new index.html file on your machine and try loading that test.css. It just won't work due to lack of permissions.

Go to test-bucket/test.css and make the object publicly available, so the browser can load it successfully.

If you don't know how to make an object publicly available, I suggest you follow this [article](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/read-access-objects-s3-bucket/) on the Knowledge Center by AWS.